# If$\ f(a)<0<f(b)$ prove there is a $t$ such that $f(t)=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The problem:

Let $D^2=\left\{q\in \mathbb R^2:||q||\le1\right\}$, let $f:D^2\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Prove that if $a,b\in D$ and $f(a)<0<f(b)$ then there is a $t$ such that $f(t)=0$. ($||\cdot||$ is the norm)

What I tried:

I was suggested by my instructor to parametrize the line that goes through the points $a$ and $b$, then apply the *intermediate value theorem* to get the result, so, with that in mind...

I know that$\ D$ is a closed set.

A parametrization of the line that joins $a$ and $b$ is $$r(t)=a+t(b-a)$$ with $0≤t≤1$.

And I thought about using the *Bolzano's theorem* (If a continuous function has values of opposite sign inside an interval, then it has a root in that interval).

I gathered all this information, but I do not know how to proceed, any tips?

Comment: Can you prove this when $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: What is $f \circ r$?

Comment: So, if I define$\ h(t)=f(r(t))$ then, since$\ h$ is continuous in [0,1] then I can just use the intermediate value theorem, right?